# How to exclude a particular table in postgres backup using pgbackrest?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pgbackrest

Trying to exclude a particular table alone during postgres backup. Is there something similar in pgbackrest like pg_dump

pg_dump --exclude-table-data=ex_table demodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found such option in pbBackRest and that is expected because it's a physical backup tool and not a logical backup tool like pg_dump.